# Specify default provider in Vagrantfile

Tags: vagrant

I'd like to specify directly in the vagrantfile which provider to use by default for each VM.

For example, given this vagrantfile:

```rb
# Vagrantfile
[...]
config.vm.define 'dev_vm' do |machine|
  machine.vm.provider :libvirt do |os|
   [...]
  end
  # machine.default_provider = :libvirt
end

config.vm.define 'production_vm' do |machine|
  machine.vm.provider :openstack do |os|
   [...]
  end
  # machine.default_provider = :openstack
end
```

To boot up the following to VMs, I have to issue two commands currently:

```sh
vagrant up --provider=libvirt  dev_vm
vagrant up --provider=openstack production_vm
```

I'd like to bring up both with a single `vagrant up`, especially because I'm running quite a few more machines. Some configuration like the commented `machine.default_provider = :openstack` would be fantastic to have.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Please note that you only need one set of backticks to engage `code formatting`.  Nesting them also works, but is not needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way to do it. Vagrant will currently use the same provider during the whole run so it could possibly be quite big code change to support this.

Maybe wrapper scripts are the easiest solution now.

Another workaround would be to use separate Vagrantfiles for the VMs and set `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` in each. If there is a lot of common config, you could extract it to e.g. `Vagrantfile.common`, which is included by the others. Something like:

```
# Vagrantfile 1

ENV['VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER'] = 'libvirt'

# assume the common config is in parent directory
load File.expand_path('../../Vagrantfile.common', __FILE__)

Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Please not that actual environment variable is `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` . Ref https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/default.html